# Am unable to sort Configurable products

Tags: magento-1.7

Am working on a shopping cart site now and am unable to sort the products based on the price.. I have drink size as the configurable product and there are several drink sizes for a single product e.g 100 ml, 250 ml, 500 ml.. The price should be sorted as per the minimum quantity but its not sorting like that..

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with configurable products (or any time you're dealing with a concept for only one type of product, as configurable attributes are), you'll probably be working with `getTypeInstance`. See below, I grab the configurable attributes for the product, then find the one for size. You could also just run through every configurable attribute if you wanted. Or if size is the only configurable attribute, just skip that `if()`.

```
$attrs  = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($_product);
foreach($attrs as $attr) {
    if(0 == strcmp("size", $attr['attribute_code'])) {
        $options    = $attr['values'];
        foreach($options as $option) {
            print "{$option['store_label']}<br />";
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

You just need set the sort order for the drink size attribute options under

```
Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes > [Your Attribute] > Manage Label / Options
```

The sort order of the options listed there will set the sort order for the options list in the configurable options dropdown. POC using sample data:

[image: Screenshot of attribute option admin view]

Here's the effect visible on the site frontend:

[image: Screenshot of frontend display of attribute options]